# Regexp - Get everything before two different strings. One can contain both

Tags: regex

I have to use regexp.

Current state:
`.+?((/=\.czxy)|(?=\.zzzz))`

It's working for the first two cases (that's obvious)

So I have decided to do something like this:
`.+?((/=\.czxy)|(?=\.zzzz)|(?=\-\-[0-9]))`

But this still doesn't work. (There is OR).

I want to have everything before the extension. (Example 1 and 2)
When string is ended with '--1,--2, --3... and so on', I need to have everything before that. (Example 3 and 4)

Note: I cannot use if construction.

Examples:

- 123_abc_cb1.czxy -> 123_abc_cb1
- 123_23c_cb1.zzzz -> 123_23c_cb1
- 123_abc_cb1--1.czxy -> 123_abc_cb1
- 123_23c_cb1--1.zzzz -> 123_23c_cb1

EDIT:
123_abc_cb1 is a random combination of letters, numbers and special characters, there can be everything.

Comment: are you looking for `.+?(?=(--\d)?\.(czxy|zzzz))` ?

Comment: `^(.*?)(?:--\d+)?\.(?:czxy|zzzz)$` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt has these issues:

- A typo: `(/=` should be `(?=`
- The regex does not require that the `--[0-9]` part is still followed by the extension. That part should actually be an optional part that precedes the pattern for the extension.

So change to this:

```
^.+?(?=(?:--\d)?\.(?:czxy|zzzz))
```

Or -- if matches do not necessarily start at the start of the input/line:

```
(?<!\S).+?(?=(?:--\d)?\.(?:czxy|zzzz))
```

Comment: The second option is fine, it's working, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any lookarounds if you can use a capture group. To match characters and underscore you can use for example `\w` to match word characters:

```
(\w+)(?:--\d+)?\.(?:czxy|zzzz)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1tCdcB/1)

Comment: But what if I cannot use groups (didn't check it before to be 100% sure)? And as I forgot to mention: 123_abc_cb1 is a random combination of letters, numbers and special characters, there can be everything. (Don't care about it).

Comment: @BartekDettlaff What is the tool or language? If there can be just anything except newlines `(.+?)(?:--\d+)?\.(?:czxy|zzzz)\b` See https://regex101.com/r/BrNGpI/1

Comment: The tools is my clients which name I cannot say. (Basically, I don't know what is the language). Moreover - I've checked what you have sent and as I said - I don't want to have group, just match. Without this, it won't work in a tool.

Comment: @BartekDettlaff Did you try the pattern provided by [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953761/5424988)?

Comment: @trincot I've checked the second option and it's working. :)

Comment: @BartekDettlaff Great that you found a working solution. Consider accepting their answer.

Answer (score 0):

why not use the recurrent information "_cb1"

```
/.*_cb1/
```

Comment: This _cb1 is just example - there can be almost everything.